# Big website architecture question

Tags: .net, asp.net, architecture

For a website that should allow searching based on a few filters on about 100 millions records, is it good enough to pick [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for searching?

The website would be written in C#, (asp.net mvc), the backend database with user data and shopping cart should be SQL Server 2008R2. Does it scale ok for 10 million users?
Other stuff that should be used: Memcached, HAProxy probably...

Comment: 10 million users ... per hour? per day? per week? per month?

Comment: The question is too vague and the potential metrics way too high to elicit any kind of valuable answer.

Comment: SO uses SqlServer and ASP.net mvc.

Comment: @Andreas: 10 million users is just the number of registered users

Comment: Solr is built with Java and would have to run in a Servlet container, separate to your ASP.NET site. You would be able to make calls to it via its web service API, but it's an extra layer of indirection and a potential bottleneck. It uses Lucene under the hood so you could theoretically do your own thing with Lucene.Net and not have to deal with Java Appservers at all.

Comment: @jgauffin Acutually SO uses Lucene.NET too. [link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not directly worked with solr, but it is highly scalable and I have worked at a company that used it for asp.net webform sites wtih extremely high traffic (e.g. a national newspaper, online magazines). Yes, it is based in Java so there would definitely be a mismatch in technology, but it scales very well with replication and 'sharding' technology. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solr).
It's also fairly stable - it was created in 2004. You can see a number of very large traffic sites that use it [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PublicServers)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't received any answers since the question is a bit vague.

It all depends on what the records contains and what your "filters" are.

The best way is really to create a program than generates millions of record and then try to do some searching.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which is also based on Lucene